# I have a Layover in Japan, Going to stayfor a month, Do I need a Transit Visa?

Tags: visas, transit, japan, philippines

I am a citizen of the US and I will be leaving to go back to the states after a long time overseas. I've been living in the Philippines and I will have a connecting flight from the Philippines to Japan and I will be staying there for about a month to live with my family before I fly back to San Francisco.
Basically my flight pattern is **MNL - NRT - 1 month - HND - SFO**
Do I need to get a transit visa? Or Is it no longer needed? 
Is there any other requirements that I may not know about?

Comment: You plan to stay in Japan for a month? That's a little longer than what would normally consider a layover. Most "transit" visas are ~24 hours.

Comment: Yes in aviation parlance it is a stopover not a transit nor a layover

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that 1 month is counted as a layover. But you don't need to get a visa, provided you are travelling on your US passport. The only thing they *may* ask you for is proof that you have booked flights leaving the country, but you are covered there.

According to the [Japanese Embassy in the US](http://www.us.emb-japan.go.jp/english/html/travel_and_visa/travel_and_visa_index.htm)

> A visa is NOT necessary for US passport holders visiting Japan for a short-term stay of less than 90 days with the purpose of tourism and business. *